# Cycles Rendering Issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, uv, shaders, normals

I have an issue..when I use cycles render and I use color,  normal,occlusion and spec map I see some lines.(I think they are the marked seam lines).It look like the 1st picture here.

[image: with all maps]

[image]

But when I take them off and keep just the color map it looks normal.
[image: with color map]

Any ideas guys how to fix that?Is a common problem to me and I have to find a solution:P Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you please make the node trees more readable?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just a tiling texture?

Comment: Here are the node trees http://imgur.com/vyNwwEF

Comment: It looks like the normal map is using different texture coordinates than the other maps.  Try deleting the *Texture Coordinate* node at the bottom left.

Comment: Still nothing :/

Answer (score 1):

I have received your scene and have found the problems. There are some issues with your scene. I will send you the modified files via mail.
Here is a first screenshot for the audience with the solutions for your problem.

1. You are not using any dilation in your images. (This is not a real problem, but would be better). Dilations can be done with tools like xNormal.
2. Your normal map is strange and produce extreme curved borders. Together with the dilation problem it produces the main issues to your result. I guess you used a filter to produce your maps like normals, depth etc. This is not really a good way. You should use a better filter for such things or better color templates.
3. Your mesh need some editing. You are using "custom splits normals data" in your mesh. Remove this data and smooth the mesh. Add an own smoothing value to the mesh then. For example a smoothing of 20 degrees. This makes nice architectual shapes and helps to remove the smooth edges too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Proposal: How about plug the normalmap output into the normal inputs of your diffuse and glossy nodes instead of the material output node displacement input?
[image: How to connect the normalmap]

Comment: thank you for your interest and your proposal but still I can see the lines..

Comment: Any chance to send your file? You could just add a example object instead of yours, if it is under a NDA. And the linked material. So we could check this.